# android toolbar: how to have a toolbar with image in the background and menu items on top

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Using material design how to create a toolbar with background image.

the following is what i want:

[image: toolbar with image and overflow and search menu icon.]

I am trying the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/actionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp" 
    android:minHeight="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewplaces"
        android:src="@drawable/puri" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and what i am getting is:

[image]

Comment: tried using 'background' attribute rather than 'src'?

Comment: I tried. Its the same. the image dont cover the entier toolbar area.

Comment: use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` for ImageView as Toolbar is `match_parent` so in order to apply image all over Toolbar. You should modify ImageView width to `match_parent`. `wrap_content` will display image width and height according to image provided in ImageView

Comment: I tried that still image does not occupy full toolbar. First of all is it possible. To place menu items and child views relatively in toolbar

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you insist on using an ImageView over using the `.setBackground(...)` function.

You can try using a `RelativeLayout` with the `Toolbar` overlaying an `ImageView` like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewplaces"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where to mention the heights for the toolbar

Comment: The android:adjustViewBounds="true" property of the ImageView will scale the Image to fit the window. This means the relationship between the width and height of your source image is kept, wile the layout_width is being stretched to match_parent witch is the width of the screen in this case

Answer (score 6):

A more proper solution would be to use an `AppBarLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:src="@drawable/bg"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of adding an element with the image to the toolbar add the image as background of the toolbar, code below.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/actionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/puri"
    android:minHeight="200dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

If you want to change it in java code, you can call `toolbar.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(yourcontext, R.drawable/puri);`

Comment: I can add that way. I knew that. But i want to add it using imageview. I want image to be  a seperate view. So that i can use croping and scaling easily

Comment: Okey, sorry. For ImageViews you can set the `scaleType`  attribute with the value `centerCrop`, or another value, have you tried it already? And also, why are you setting the `layout_width` to `wrap_content`?