# Toolbar background is working with mipmap and not drawable

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I'm using background image in my toolbar, and from some reason the toolbar is working only with mipmap and not with drawable.

In my app_bar_main.xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@mipmap/bar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

As you can see I've used mipmap instead of drawable, though when I'm using drawable the application crashes and the following error is given:

> Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating
>   class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Must mention this mipmap using is just making my app very slow, and it skipping frames, so I would like to change it to drawable.

How can I change the toolbar background resource of the image from mipmap to drawable?

EDIT:

Style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="LightDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
        <item name="background">@drawable/bar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: What is your `suppport library to 23.2.1` ?

Comment: @Ninja Where can I check the support? My build gradle file says that: 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your xml file is perfect. 
What I suggest ,Just resize that image or prepare background image with different different size, which you want to set in to your toolbar and put it in to different drawables / mipmap folders.

> android:background="@mipmap/bar"

as we know icon size should be ,

> - drawable-ldpi (120 dpi, Low density screen) - 36px x 36px
> - drawable-mdpi (160 dpi, Medium density screen) - 48px x 48px
> - drawable-hdpi (240 dpi, High density screen) - 72px x 72px
> - drawable-xhdpi (320 dpi, Extra-high density screen) - 96px x 96px

run your app again and do let me know .

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code in your app level `build.gradle` file

```
android {  
   defaultConfig {
     .....
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }  
 }
```

**toolbar_default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"/>
```

**ToolBarStyle**

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="">
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
        <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
 </style>
```

> Other
>   Please remove below line from you toolbar and try to check it work or not.I am not sure but you just check it.

```
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Comment: What is your style of your `toolbar`?

Comment: I want image background to my toolbar, that's not helping me.

Answer (score 0):

toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/MyToolbarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
```

Themes/Style

```
<style name="MyToolbarStyle">
<item name="android:maxHeight">@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material</item>
<item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
<item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
<item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/Theme.Toolbar.Title</item>
<!-- No need for colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark, colorAccent here
     this should go to the AppTheme -->
```

Try this methos,it works..

Comment: Wondering how is that related to my code, the image background isn't included here.

Comment: I am not sure but if you need to set the backgroup as image you need to use mipmap

Comment: Though mipmap make my app running slow (Very slow)

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607496/android-toolbar-how-to-have-a-toolbar-with-image-in-the-background-and-menu-ite ...see the first answer you can try that